# Remove a not owned URL or permalink from Google search results

Tags: indexing, permalinks, privacy, google-index

I would like to remove an old search result from Google searches which I am not the owner. When the content no longer exists or has been changed, Google offers the removal tool, but I don't know how to do it when it's the permalink what has been changed.

E.g: www."dummy_domain".com/hello -> www."dummy_domain".com/goodbye

The page content is the same but the permalink has been changed and Google is still indexing the old permalink

Answer (score 0):

Use Google's [search console](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663419?hl=en) to remove URL(s).

Comment: I have removed a lot of obsolete pages with this tool, but it doesn't work when the page content is ok but the permalink doesn't. Google is indexing the old search result to the new content. Or may I don't know to do it. If you could be more specific.